# HTML form and PHP function to save form data to mysql in same file/page

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, post

I won't purport to know exactly what I am doing with this because I don't and that's probably painfully obvious.  I am trying to keep the form and the function to update the database in the same file.  What am I doing wrong?

Here are the important bits:

HTML:

```
<form id="billing" action="?updatebilling" method="post">
```

PHP:

```
<!-- Function to update billing -->
<?php 
function updatebilling() {
    // Connecting to the MySQL server
    $host="localhost";
    $user_name="root";
    $pwd="bluebox";
    $database_name="rewired";
    $db=mysql_connect($host, $user_name, $pwd) or die(mysql_error());
    if (mysql_error() > "") print mysql_error() . "<br>";
    mysql_select_db($database_name, $db);
    if (mysql_error() > "") print mysql_error() . "<br>";

    // Static info - account number
    $account_id=users::getAttr('Account', 'account_id');

    // Storing form values into PHP variables
    $zip = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['billingzip']);
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);


    // Inserting variables into database
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `web_signup`
      SET `account_id` = '{$account_id}',
     `zip` = '{$billingzip}',
     `cardholder_name` = '{$name}',
     `updated_at` = NOW()";

    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error().$sql);

    mysql_close($db);

}   ?>
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Should keep your database connection on a separate secure page. Also, you can't use that as a form action. Should be `<form id='billing' action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>' method='post'>`. If you're new to the game, use `new mysqli()` and Object Oriented PHP. It will save a lot of keystrokes!

Comment: So how do you actually call the function? What specific problems are you having?

Comment: How does this function have access to anything static?

Answer (score 0):

Your `<form>` tag is odd.

```
<form id="billing" action="?updatebilling" method="post">
```

This will reload the same page, but the `?updatebilling` action is meaningless. You need to check what's being submitted at the top of your page and act accordingly. Many check for the `submit` button, and branch to the processing code if they find it.

```
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   // echo form here
} else {
   // process submitted data here.
}
```

Your `action` can then be left blank or set to point to the page file name with `action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>'`

Comment: @PHPglue Oops! Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer might be a bit obvious here. Are you calling the function after submission? From what I can see in your code you have an HTML form defined and your code defines a function to save the data to the database but are you actually executing the function? Eg:

```
<?php
// function to save billing info
function updatebilling() { ... }

if (isset($_POST)) { // only call function when a post request is being processed
  updatebilling(); // execute function to save the billing info
}
?>
<form action="?updatebilling" method="post">
  <!-- your inputs here -->
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```